# Using Json On PHP Foreach With HTML For Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

Could someone please help me out.

How can i put this foreach statement in json_encode for example.

```
<?php foreach ($movies as $movie) { ?>

  <div>
    <h3><?php echo $movie['title']; ?><h3>
    <img src="/somewhere/<?php echo movie['image']; ?>" />
  </div>

<?php } ?>
```

So what i want to do is pass all movies from the foreach to json function So i can pass it to ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: path+'/ajax/somefile.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {page: requestTime},
  success: function(response) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(response.data);
    var $row = $('<div></div>', { 'class': 'row', style: 'display: none;' }).html(data.join(''));
    $row.appendTo('#movie-rating-grid').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Could someone explain or show how to do this thanks

Comment: What you want to achieve? Provide more information. You show 2 parts of working code and so?

Comment: If you're just going to dump everything in a `div`, you don't really need json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to update your PHP to have only PHP instead of breaking out of PHP to have HTML.

somefile.php

```
foreach ($movies as $movie) { 
    $html = '
    <div>
        <h3>'.$movie['title'].'<h3>
        <img src="/somewhere/'.$movie['image'].'" alt="'.$movie['title'].'" />
    </div>
';
    $array[] = $html;
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

With this approach, you won't need to assign response to data.

movies.html

```
success: function(data) {
    var $row = $('<div></div>', { 'class': 'row', style: 'display: none;' }).html(data.join(''));
    $row.appendTo('#movie-rating-grid').fadeIn();
}
```

You could, also, adjust the PHP to give you output like `$array[] = array('title' => $movie['title'], 'image' => $movie['image']);` and then add the necessary HTML markup in your JavaScript success function.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to encode your movies array as a json string.

`$movies_json_string = json_encode($movies);`

Then, you simply need to echo it.

`echo $movies_json_string`;

When ajax retrieves this view, it will interpret it as a json string and appropriately convert it to a json array.